# add dynamic parameter in <form Action="">

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

below my code

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form action="http://localhost:9767/ProspectWorxService.svc/SaveUploadedFile?Id=" name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

i would like to add dynamic id in `action = "http://localhost:9767/ProspectWorxService.svc/SaveUploadedFile?Id=" + globalId`
like above one, globalId as javascript veriable.

but its in html so how could in pass parameter ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)** method with callback function to update the `action` attribute value. The callback function have two paramters index and previous value.

```js
var globalId = 2;
$('#form').attr('action', function(i, v) {
  return v + global;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <form id="form" action="http://localhost:9767/ProspectWorxService.svc/SaveUploadedFile?Id=" name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply,, id merge to url but in server end id value in not been generated. please give me full source url if available.

Comment: while i request to WCF Service, need to pass id, as per your help url updated but in server side (WCF) id is not updated

Comment: so while requesting to WCF service then i need to update URL

Comment: @JimmyDarji : are you using ajax for  requesting to WCF service

Comment: Yes, I am using ajax and WCF service

Comment: ok actually the div "jumbotron" when i drag and drop one image to that div it call WCF service, there is no such a click event or something to call your function, and i used this function while create uniq id.

Comment: You can use drop event

Answer (score 0):

You state that the `globalId` variable is in your JS code, and have tagged jQuery, so here's a jQuery solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dropzoneForm').prop('action', function(i, val) {
        return val + globalId;
    });
});
```